# I'm not able to change widget size

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm new in all widget staff so I'm trying to make one simple that just shows a name on it. I have read several tutorials but I'm not able to change the size! It's not that I want to try to change it at runtime its that I change the size from the widget provider and it doesn't change!!

Any help on this!

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:minHeight="146dp"
android:minWidth="146dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="10000" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So what is the problem? You should change minHeight and minWidth. But remember that the size should match the formula (num*74 - 2).

And after you've changed the size you should reinstall the package and add new widget to the screen.

Comment: Ok! I feel stupid now! I wasn't reinstalling the widget so the size wasn't changing! Thank you very much!